# Dynamic Conditional Formatting (last cell with value +1)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to format the cell after I have no Numbers. 
Example:

```
    A1=3
    A2=1
    A3=8
    A4=3
    A5=1
    A6=8
```

By using the formula

```
Match(99^99,A:A,1)+1
```

I'm able to find the row successfully (7).

So, by plugging the formula

```
Address(Match(99^99,A:A,1)+1,1)
```

I'm able to find the cell I need to format.

What I wasn't able to do was use a custom formula to conditionally format that cell.

Would be really grateful if you have a solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it with the following formula:

```
=address(MATCH(99^99,A:A,1)+1,1)="$A$"&row()
```

The first part of the formula references the cell I want to format. After the "=", by using row(), it returns the current row.

Since the range of Conditional formatting is applied to A:A, it must go through every single cell and test the formula.

That means that it will use row() in A1, returning 1 (A1 is row 1), then A2, returning 2 and so on, it translates to this {1,2,3,4,5,6 ...}

Because of the "=" sign, This formula Will ONLY apply when both sides are equal.
To the left of the "=", the returned value is $A$6, to the right of the formula, $A$1, $A$2, $A$3 ... $A$6... Is returned.

Since both sides must be equal to activate the formatting, ONLY $A$6 returns true.